# Error: EROFS: read-only file system, mkdir '/home/sbx_user1063' when deploy using serverless

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, serverless

I'm using babel-register package. It has cache folder to save cache files. It is working fine locally and EC2, but when i'm trying to deploy using serverless it is throwing *Error: EROFS: read-only file system* error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

When using lambda, the only location you can write to is /tmp/. You must figure out how to tell babel-register to use /tmp/ as it's directory for saving cache files.

> Each Lambda function receives 500MB of non-persistent disk space in its own /tmp directory.

*Source: https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/faqs/*